# “Attempting to use an incompatible return type” error

Tags: java, наследование

Не совсем понятно почему в классе наследнике нельзя переопределить метод и изменить возвращаемый тип.

Например:

```
class SuperClass { 
    public DeclareInfo doDeclare(Object data){
       ...
       return new DeclareInfo(data)
    }
}
```

изменить возвращаемый тип в классе наследнике при овверрайде метода

```
class ChildClass extends SuperClass {

     @Override
     public Integer doDeclare(Object data){
        ...
        return 1;
     }
}
```

### Ошибка

При этом если создается объект класса наследника вызывать метод с return Integer, если супер класс return DeclareInfo. Почему добавили такое ограничение?

---

Comment: Зачем вам переопределять метод если вы задаете другой возвращаемый тип? Не знаю как в Java, в c# можно поставить ключевое слово new для таких методов, тем самым сообщая компилятору что у класса потомка будет другой метод с этим же именем, что и у базового класса.

Comment: @Anamnian вопрос, на минуточку, про Java. Не упоминайте C# всуе )

Comment: @Suvitruf лишь привел аналогию из другого языка. В java нет похожего по поведению ключевого слова?

Comment: @Anamnian не припомню такого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое ограничение появилось потому, что иначе, если у вас:

```
SuperClass obj = new ChildClass()
DeclareInfo info = obj.doDeclare(data);
```

произойдёт неявная попытка кастинга `Integer` в `DeclareInfo`, но `Integer` в `DeclareInfo` не кастится.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, можно, если [возвращаемые типы ковариантны (jls-8.4.5)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5). Вот такое работать будет:

```
class SuperClass { 
    public ParentReturnType doDeclare(Object data){
       ...
       return null;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends SuperClass {

     @Override
     public ChildReturnType doDeclare(Object data){
        ...
        return null;
     }
}

private class ParentReturnType {

}

private class ChildReturnType extends ParentReturnType {
}
```

Если говорить про теоретический аспект, то, думаю, стоит упомянуть [Принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).